# Dynamic url mapping to different servlets in tomcat

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web.xml, tomcat8

I want to map this url to one servlet:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/dynamic-user-name/edit
```

And this to another servlet:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/dynamic-user-name
```

where `dynamic-user-name` will change depending on which user enters.

I have tried the following but it seems like the `/*` will direct everything.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>userservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>edituser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.EditUserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>userservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>edituser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users/*/edit</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is it possible to map them separately in some way? I'm using a tomcat server.

**Solution/workaround** (not mapped to different servlets)

I solved it without `web.xml` and instead used `getRequestUrl();` in the servlet with some regex, but I'm still looking for a more clean solution since this ends up with a lot of if-statements.

```
String uri = URLDecoder.decode( request.getRequestURI(), "UTF-8" ).toLowerCase();  
if(uri.matches("/users/(.*?)/edit")){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/users/(.*?)/edit");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(uri);

        if (matcher.find())
        {
            String username = matcher.find(1);
            // Do stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: 1)Servlets are not designed to work in this way.2) It is really not a conventional way to use url path. Why do you want to do it ?

Comment: I used request.getRequestURI() to see which requests the users did earlier but it got kinda messy so I'm searching for a more elegant way to structure the code. @davidxxx